# FadeIn new URL with Jquery

Tags: jquery, fadein

How can I fadeIn the new URL after the video goes off, instead of it just popping on while  using the fadeIn(); code or any other code?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function removeFlash(){
    $("#videoBg").empty();
    $("#videoBg").animate( { top:"-9999px"}, 1 );
    window.location.assign("http://???.com")
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your questions correctly, I would do something similar to this:

```
$("#url").hide();
$("#url").fadeIn('fast');
```

If the URL is there already. Hide it and FadeIn back...

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the page [navigating] to a new page. The current page can not do anything with the new page. If you want to fade in the new page, the code has to be placed on the new page source.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not loading the new url asynchronously you have no control over its content.
That said, you can use events and hook some animation to the page load/unload.

To achieve the effect you describe you can:

1. `hide` content on `document.ready`
2. `fadeIn` content on `window.load`
3. `fadeOut` content on `window.beforeUnload`

You have to include this script in **every page**.

I've not tested this, but it should work. The implementation is very easy using some basic jQuery method.